# Error while building an Json api : No route matches [GET] "/v1/posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

I was trying to build a json api  for my application

This is my ROUTES.RB FILE

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
devise_for :users
namespace :api , :path =>"", :constraints => {:subdomain =>"api"} , defaults: {format: 'json'} do

namespace :v1 do
  resources :posts do
   resources :comments
  end
 end
end

 #  namespace :v1 do
 #   resources :posts, only: [:index]
  #end  
          #end

root 'posts#index'

end
```

and i created another folder under Controller to use namespace

I created "api" folder and under that v1 folder, and under that a posts_controller.rb file
this is  exact path
" /app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb "

```
     class Api::V1::PostsController < ApplicationController

       protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
       before_action :destroy_session

      def index
        @posts=Post.all

         respond_to  do |format|
              format.json { render json: @posts}
         end

      end

      private
       def destroy_session
       request.session_options[:skip]= true
     end


   end
```

and i do have data in the postscontroller and associations are also made.

Actually what i need is , when i access this Url  http://api.localhost:3000/v1/posts 
i need the data in the posts as in  json format present in the browser

But its showing this error

> No route matches [GET] "/v1/posts"

How can i fix this error ?

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your `:posts` resources directly, and namespaced it under `api` > `v1`. You can access `http://api.localhost:3000/posts` but you can't access the under `v1`. You need to add namespace to it like this

```
namespace :v1 do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

What you've done is you've namespaced your `v1` inside `api`. You can take the above approach or try accessing like `http://api.localhost:3000/api/v1/posts`

> Update:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  devise_for :users

  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :posts do
        resources :comments
      end
    end
  end

  #The below part to access everything the regular way(non-api way)
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

 #namespace :v1 do
 #  resources :posts, only: [:index]
 #end  
 #end

 root 'posts#index'

end
```

Update your routes file to the following. And try accessing these two urls

http://localhost:3000/posts

http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts

You can not access sub domains in your localhost without extra configuration. So try the new routes code, without `constraints` in your route.

Comment: I edited as you said , but it still showing the error, and i tried accessing http://api.localhost:3000/api/v1/posts , but it also shows the "route error"

Comment: Is it the same route error? Can you update your question's router file with the new content?

Comment: Updated as you said , now i am getting more errors, can't access the localhost:3000/posts too!!

Comment: the first url works, but the second one is givinge  "error " No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/posts"

Comment: Did you remove `api` sub domain and the contraints from your `api` namespace?

Comment: yeah, i accessed http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts , and copied your updated code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114603/discussion-between-kumar-abinash-and-user3260316).